# Image and text going out of div while resizing - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Recently I started learning bootstrap and decided to build a simple page to sum up F1 races. Unfortunately, I've got something seriously mixed up because the image of the race driver and the text with the name of the driver who set the fastest lap goes beyond the div when you resize the browser. I would be grateful if someone pointed out my mistake because I have no idea how to fix it.
Here are the screenshots:

[normal browser size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awkhh.jpg)

[resized_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqUgL.png)

[resized_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csYaT.png)

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Najważniejsze wydarzenia F1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../fontello/css/fontello.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../flag-icon-css-master/css/flag-icon.css" type="text/css"/>        

    <script src="../../raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../justgage.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

        var g1 = new JustGage({
            id: "g1",
            relativeGaugeSize: true,
            titleFontFamily: "Formula1",
            titleFontColor: "black",
            valueFontFamily: "Formula1",
            value: 9,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            decimals: 0,
            gaugeWidthScale: 0.6,
            customSectors: [{
            color : "#13B5EA",
            lo : 0,
            hi : 2
            },{
            color : "#4BB97E",
            lo : 2,
            hi : 4
            },{
            color : "#FDCB2A",
            lo : 4,
            hi : 6
            },{
            color : "#F78934",
            lo : 6,
            hi : 8
            },{
            color : "#F25258",
            lo : 8,
            hi : 10
            }]
        });
        

        });
    </script>
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row no-gutters">
        
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="next_prev">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-left-open" id="navi" title="Poprzedni wyścig"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Grand Prix Chin 2016</h1>
                    <p><i class="icon-clock"></i>08:00
                    <i class="icon-location"></i>Shanghai International Circuit
                    <i class="icon-calendar-empty"></i>17.04
                    <i class="icon-flag-checkered"></i>56 Okrążeń</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="next_prev">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; underline: none;">
                    <i class="icon-right-open" id="navi" title="Następny wyścig"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 px-0">
        <div class="podium">
            <img src="../../img/podiums/3_Chiny.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub">
                <h1>Ocena wyścigu:</h1>
                <div id="g1" class="gauge"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub">
                <h1>Kierowca wyścigu:</h1>
                <p><img class="dotd img-responsive" src="../../img/dotd/2016/3_Chiny.jpg"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub">
                <h1>Najszybsze okrążenie:</h1>
                <p id="fastest_lap">1:39.824</p>
                <p><img src="../../img/fast_lap_head/2016/3_Chiny.png" style="height: 50%;">
                <h3>Nico <span style="font-weight:bold;">Hülkenberg</span></h3>Force India</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>2019</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: Formula1; 
src: url('Formula1-Regular.ttf'); 
}


@font-face{ 
font-family: Formula1;
font-weight: bold;
src: url('Formula1-Bold.ttf');
}

body{
font-family: Formula1, sans-serif;
color: black;
}

.header h1{
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 50px;
}

.header p{
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#navi{
font-size: 60px;
}

.next_prev{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-left-open:hover, .icon-right-open:hover{
color: #f3f3f3;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.footer{
text-align: center;
}

.banner_sub{
text-align: center;
height: 380px;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-right: solid 2px #d0d0d2;
border-bottom: solid 2px #d0d0d2;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.banner_sub:hover{
border-right: solid 2px #e10600;
border-bottom: solid 2px #e10600;
}

.gauge{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: -70px;
}


#fastest_lap{
color: purple;
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

.dotd{
border-radius: 20px;
margin-top: 35px;
width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Not tested, but I would think `shrink-to-fit=no` in the meta tag is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face{ 
font-family: Formula1; 
src: url('Formula1-Regular.ttf'); 
}


@font-face{ 
font-family: Formula1;
font-weight: bold;
src: url('Formula1-Bold.ttf');
}

body{
font-family: Formula1, sans-serif;
color: black;
}

.header h1{
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 50px;
}

.header p{
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#navi{
font-size: 60px;
}

.next_prev{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.icon-left-open:hover, .icon-right-open:hover{
color: #f3f3f3;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.footer{
text-align: center;
}

.banner_sub{
text-align: center;
height: 380px;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-right: solid 2px #d0d0d2;
border-bottom: solid 2px #d0d0d2;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.banner_sub:hover{
border-right: solid 2px #e10600;
border-bottom: solid 2px #e10600;
}

.gauge{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin-top: -70px;
}


#fastest_lap{
color: purple;
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

.dotd{
border-radius: 20px;
margin-top: 35px;
width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Najważniejsze wydarzenia F1</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../fontello/css/fontello.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../flag-icon-css-master/css/flag-icon.css" type="text/css"/>        

    <script src="../../raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../justgage.js"></script>
   
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row no-gutters">
        
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="next_prev">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-left-open" id="navi" title="Poprzedni wyścig"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Grand Prix Chin 2016</h1>
                    <p><i class="icon-clock"></i>08:00
                    <i class="icon-location"></i>Shanghai International Circuit
                    <i class="icon-calendar-empty"></i>17.04
                    <i class="icon-flag-checkered"></i>56 Okrążeń</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="next_prev">
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; underline: none;">
                    <i class="icon-right-open" id="navi" title="Następny wyścig"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="col-sm-12 px-0">
        <div class="podium">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-1FzuZdh0Ec8/Xy6JOVeLMzI/AAAAAAAAD5Q/qvuhsNEFGQ46HWItzqbe7alwRnKVkSZXgCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-08-08.png" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub">
                <h1>Ocena wyścigu:</h1>
                 <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-8G2bsRRxhTU/Xy6CKatoxFI/AAAAAAAAD5E/eHIxj438C0oRwTZQ33qs0qQW2VIj09nVwCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-08-08.png" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub clearfix">
                <h1>Kierowca wyścigu:</h1>
                <p><img class="dotd img-responsive" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WLMLKp68bNI/Xy6BYeXRAdI/AAAAAAAAD48/Ffl7HUCROhgQAZr9UnHaRHfm1Ls9HfnFgCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-08-08.png"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="banner_sub clearfix">
                <h1>Najszybsze okrążenie:</h1>
                <p id="fastest_lap">1:39.824</p>
                <p><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kAUGg3URGS4/Xy6BVTVSwLI/AAAAAAAAD44/KnjWX9p1kzoof-6ok7aPwyXywQMJon3OQCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2020-08-08.png" style="height: 50%;">
                <h3>Nico <span style="font-weight:bold;">Hülkenberg</span></h3>Force India</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>2019</p>
    </div>
    
    </div>
        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. When the page is resized to a width of 915 px, the image is still out of the div.